# Can size of .obj models can be adjust (scenekit)

Tags: ios, xcode, model, scenekit

I am new to Scenekit coding . i just want to know that can the size of the models or objects be adjusted using the utilities in the xcode ? .
I am troubled searching for the small objects .
Any help is Apprectiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on the inspector view with the object selected, you can resize.

Here an example

[image]

Comment: but can the bounding box width, height and depth will change???

Comment: boundingBox property is auto-calculated for sceneKit they contain all the objects on the node.